# hibernate.cfg.xml not found, but i wrote it

Tags: java, hibernate

hey i get an  Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]

but i wrote it like you can see in the picture [image]

does anyone know why?
this is my output:
[image]
and this is my main:

[image]

Comment: Try to put your file in _src/main/resources_ instead.

Comment: i did, now i get a NoSuchMethodError: NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()                                                                          at Main.configurationSessionFactory(Main.java:16)
 at Main.main(Main.java:22)..... do u have another tip? :)

Comment: Can you please try  Maven->Update ???   (you use maven right??)